# Android studio intent malfunction

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to create a project where you move to the quiz application of the project after you login, but the intent part doesnt work and the application keeps closing after u input the correct
username and password ,it never moves to the next part of the project.

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView loginview;
    Button login;
    EditText name, pass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LandingPage.class);
//                    intent.putExtra("username","Admin");
//                    startActivity(intent);
        loginview = findViewById(R.id.textview);
        name = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        pass = findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        login = findViewById(R.id.button);

        login.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (name.getText().toString().equals("admin") && pass.getText().toString().equals("pass")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               ** Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                name.setText("");
                startActivity(intent);**

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login unsuccessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

*part of Mainactivity 2*``

ackage com.example.quizapplicationfinal;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView totalQuestionsTextView;
    TextView questionTextView;
    Button ansA, ansB, ansC, ansD;
    Button submitBtn;

    int score=0;
    int totalQuestion = QuestionAnswer.question.length;
    int currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    String selectedAnswer = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
`
```

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as this question has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.

Comment: If the application is closing, it is crashing. Check the logcat for the exception message and stacktrace. Edit your question and paste the exception message and stacktrace into the question.